# Adicionar Alterar Author em Edição Rápida de Type Post

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, funções, custom-post-types

Eu criei um type post para personalizar o admin do wordpress de um cliente, tudo funciona perfeitamente, porém a opção de alterar o autor do post em "edição rápida" não aparece, eu sei que por padrão ele não irá mostrar para campos personalizados, eu tenho o código para incluir no functions.php para mostrar, mas eu fiz isso e não consigo ajustar essa função, alguém sabe onde estou errando ou pode me ajudar com outra solução. Não é a configuração de Opção de Tela.Segue o Código que tenho abaixo:

```
          // ADICIONAR EDITAR AUTOR

         function allowAuthorEditing()
        {
        add_post_type_support( 'mytype', 'author' );
         }
          add_action('init','allowAuthorEditing');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei a Solução Galera, vou passar o código para analisarem como ficou a função correta.

```
                 // ADICIONAR EDITAR AUTOR

               add_action('init', 'wptips_custom_init');
                   function wptips_custom_init() {
                   add_post_type_support( 'places', array(  'author' ) );
                   }
```

Caso precise incluir outras funções é apenas necessário incluir no array o que você necessita que aparaça no type post que você criou.